# VSCode Python issues - SyntaxError: invalid syntax line 1 and also conflicting python versions cannot import requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-requests, anaconda

I'm using VSCode to create some Python scripts for a personal project. I have used VSCode without any problems in the past but I'm running into some errors now and can't figure out why.

At first I had conflicting Python versions - on the bottom bar it was Python 3.10.2 and when I use the version command in the Terminal I'm getting Python 3.9.7. Originally, I was getting errors that certain libraries were not installed - even if they were - but when I changed the bottom bar version to Python 3.9.7 ('base': conda) which is the same as the version command result - I no longer get that issue.

Instead, I now get an issue that consistently returns something like the following:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    /Users/...
 
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I can get things working on a Jupyter notebook but when I want to use scripts and keep work in folders this is causing a huge problem. Does anyone have an idea what I can do here to resolve?

Comment: That's **not** Python; it looks like the start of a path, it's unclear why you're trying to run it as Python.

Comment: Once verify the python installation on your system, you can check that by going to the command prompt and type "py" and you can see the version if Python 3.10 is installed for lower versions you can type "python".

Comment: Please show the full error message and your error code.

Comment: @Lakeside52, Is there any progress on the issue?

Comment: @JialeDu apologies for late reply - yes and no... what I've learned, and the best advice I can give on this is learn how to use virtual environments for different projects. This will prevent problems between projects and keep your projects working over time

Comment: @JialeDu try this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-setup-virtual-environments-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python

Open this link and install this extension.

Also, a step-by-step procedure is given.
A Visual Studio Code extension with rich support for the Python language (for all actively supported versions of the language: >=3.7), including features such as IntelliSense (Pylance), linting, debugging, code navigation, code formatting, refactoring, variable explorer, test explorer, and more!
Python extension does offer some support when running on vscode.dev (which includes github.dev). This includes partial IntelliSense for open files in the editor.

Comment: Thank you! How do I install the extension ?

Comment: @Steph Flint, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python